# Use Futures with Boost Thread Pool

Tags: c++, boost, future

I'm implementing a TCP client which read and send files and strings and I'm using Boost as my main library. I'd like to continue reading or sending files while I keep sending strings, which in these case are the commands to send to the server. For this purpose I thought about using a Thread Pool in order to not overload the client. My question is, can I use futures to use callbacks when on of the thread in the pool ends? In case I can't, is there any other solution?
I was doing something like this, where `pool_` is a `boost:asio:thread_pool`

```
void send_file(std::string const& file_path){
    boost::asio::post(pool_, [this, &file_path] {
        handle_send_file(file_path);
    });
    // DO SOMETHING WHEN handle_send_file ENDS
}

void handle_send_file(std::string const& file_path) {
    boost::array<char, 1024> buf{};
    boost::system::error_code error;
    std::ifstream source_file(file_path, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::ate);

    if(!source_file) {
        std::cout << "[ERROR] Failed to open " << file_path << std::endl;
        //TODO gestire errore
    }
    size_t file_size = source_file.tellg();
    source_file.seekg(0);

    std::string file_size_readable = file_size_to_readable(file_size);

    // First send file name and file size in bytes to server
    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    request_stream << file_path << "\n"
                   << file_size << "\n\n"; // Consider sending readable version, does it change anything?

    // Send the request
    boost::asio::write(*socket_, request, error);
    if(error){
        std::cout << "[ERROR] Send request error:" << error << std::endl;
        //TODO lanciare un'eccezione? Qua dovrò controllare se il server funziona o no
    }
    if(DEBUG) {
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] " << file_path << " size is: " << file_size_readable << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] Start sending file content" << std::endl;
    }

    long bytes_sent = 0;
    float percent = 0;
    print_percentage(percent);

    while(!source_file.eof()) {
        source_file.read(buf.c_array(), (std::streamsize)buf.size());

        int bytes_read_from_file = source_file.gcount(); //int is fine because i read at most buf's size, 1024 in this case

        if(bytes_read_from_file<=0) {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] Read file error" << std::endl;
            break;
            //TODO gestire questo errore
        }

        percent = std::ceil((100.0 * bytes_sent) / file_size);
        print_percentage(percent);

        boost::asio::write(*socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buf.c_array(), source_file.gcount()),
                           boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);
        if(error) {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] Send file error:" << error << std::endl;
            //TODO lanciare un'eccezione?
        }

        bytes_sent += bytes_read_from_file;
    }

    std::cout << "\n" << "[INFO] File " << file_path << " sent successfully!" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operations posted to the pool end without the threads ending. That's the whole purpose of *pooling* the threads.

```
void send_file(std::string const& file_path){
    post(pool_, [this, &file_path] {
        handle_send_file(file_path);
    });
    // DO SOMETHING WHEN handle_send_file ENDS
}
```

This has several issues. The largest one is that you should not capture `file_path` by reference, as the argument is soon out of scope, and the `handle_send_file` call will run at an unspecified time in another thread. That's a race condition and  dangling reference. [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) results.

Then the

```
    // DO SOMETHING WHEN handle_send_file ENDS
```

is on a line which has no sequence relation with `handle_send_file`. In fact, it will probably run *before* that operation ever has a chance to start.

### Simplifying

Here's a simplified version:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
    
static asio::thread_pool pool_;

struct X {
    std::unique_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_;
    
    explicit X(unsigned short port) : socket_(new tcp::socket{ pool_ }) {
        socket_->connect({ {}, port });
    }

    asio::thread_pool pool_;
    std::unique_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_{ new tcp::socket{ pool_ } };

    void send_file(std::string file_path) {
        post(pool_, [=, this] {
            send_file_implementation(file_path);
            // DO SOMETHING WHEN send_file_implementation ENDS
        });
    }

    // throws system_error exception
    void send_file_implementation(std::string file_path) {
        std::ifstream source_file(file_path,
                                  std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::ate);
        size_t file_size = source_file.tellg();
        source_file.seekg(0);

        write(*socket_,
                asio::buffer(file_path + "\n" + std::to_string(file_size) + "\n\n"));

        boost::array<char, 1024> buf{};
        while (source_file.read(buf.c_array(), buf.size()) ||
               source_file.gcount() > 0)
        {
            int n = source_file.gcount();

            if (n <= 0) {
                using namespace boost::system;
                throw system_error(errc::io_error, system_category());
            }

            write(*socket_, asio::buffer(buf), asio::transfer_exactly(n));
        }
    }
};
```

Now, you can indeed run several of these operations in parallel (assuming several instances of `X`, so you have separate `socket_` connections).

To do something at the end, just put code where I moved the comment:

```
// DO SOMETHING WHEN send_file_implementation ENDS
```

If you don't know what to do there and you wish to make a future ready at that point, you can:

```
std::future<void> send_file(std::string file_path) {
    std::packaged_task<void()> task([=, this] {
        send_file_implementation(file_path);
    });

    return post(pool_, std::move(task));
}
```

This [overload of `post`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/post/overload2.html) magically¹ returns the future from the packaged task. That packaged task will set the internal promise with either the (`void`) return value or the exception thrown.

See it in action: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e0fa253920dc126)**

```
int main() {
    // send two files simultaneously to different connections
    X clientA(6868);
    X clientB(6969);

    std::future<void> futures[] = {
        clientA.send_file("main.cpp"),
        clientB.send_file("main.cpp"),
    };

    for (auto& fut : futures) try {
        fut.get();
        std::cout << "Everything completed without error\n";
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Error occurred: " << e.what() << "\n";
    };

    pool_.join();
}
```

I tested this while running two netcats to listen on 6868/6969:

```
nc -l -p 6868 | head& nc -l -p 6969 | md5sum&
./a.out
wait
```

The server prints:

```
Everything completed without error
Everything completed without error
```

The netcats print their filtered output:

```
main.cpp
1907

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
7ecb71992bcbc22bda44d78ad3e2a5ef  -
```

---

¹ not *magic*: see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_result.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know that my first placement of `// DO SOMETHING WHEN send_file_implementation ENDS` wasn't related to the end of the function posted to the pool but I did it to show you what I meant and stupidly I didn't think that was enough to place it in the post as well.
I only need some sort of notification when the file transfer ends so maybe using a future could be unnecessary, I will stick to the first solution you gave me. Thanks a lot, I learnt how to use futures with a pool too.